# how can i save local file in django models

Tags: django

i want to save a local file in django model. and i am using this codes:

```
with open('data.json', 'w') as file:
    file.write('somethings')
    myModel.objects.create(file=file, name='name')
```

and this is my model:

```
class myModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    json = models.FileField(upload_to='files')
```

this codes save data.json in root path: [root image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3mpz.jpg)

but when i want to create model this codes raised following error:
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'field'

how can i save data.json in  myModel???

Comment: it is models.FileField. i want to save json as .json file in FileField

Comment: do you know how can i write then save in model?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [JSONField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#jsonfield) to save the data of your file as it’s JSON data…

But if you really want to save as a file, follow these steps.

---

Save your file to the server using:

```python
from django.core.files import File

with open('data.json') as file:
    myModel.objects.create(json=File(file), name='name')
```

Sources:

- [Managing Files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/files/)
- [Reading and writing files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)